# IE and Chrome calculating CSS padding differently

Tags: css

I have the following CSS and HTML:

```
    .TestPadding{
width:29px;
text-align:center;
height:18px;
padding:3px 0px 2px 0px;
margin:2px 1px;
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:13px;
border:2px solid black;
float:left;}

<div class="TestPadding">1</div>
<div class="TestPadding">2</div>
<div class="TestPadding">3</div>
<div class="TestPadding">4</div>
<div class="TestPadding">5</div>
<div class="TestPadding">6</div>
<div class="TestPadding">7</div>
<div class="TestPadding">8</div>
<div class="TestPadding">9</div>
<div class="TestPadding">10</div>
```

The problem is that the rendering is different in IE and Chrome. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Chrome is on top and IE on the bottom. On IE, the numbers don't look vertically aligned. I tried making all sorts of combinations on the CSS but none have given me a consistent vertical alignment and sizing.

**If you want to try it out, there's a [**fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GWzEr/)**.**

Thanks.

Comment: They're calculating the padding correctly. The boxes are of equal widths and heights. Why the text isn't aligned the same on both browsers is possibly another issue.

Comment: Have you tried using a CSS reset?  It'll get rid of many inconsistencies between browsers.  It will likely remove some CSS defaults you assume will be there, but it's just a matter of putting those back.  Totally worth the effort, and even more effective when you start your project with them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `line-height:18px;` and no  vertical padding (`padding:0 2px;`).

Comment: Man, I spent sooo much time on this! Thanks for the line-height suggestion; I left the padding as is and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use a little IE hack:

`_padding-top:4px` (for example)

If you do choose to go down the IE hack root, here's how to apply to the different versions of IE:

- `padding-top:4px\9;` - IE8 and below
- `*padding-top:4px;` - IE7 and below
- `_padding-top:4px;` - IE6

Al

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `padding` but use `line-height` (preferable use the unit `em`) on the `div`s.
By the way, I suggest that you even don't use `div`s but a list (`ul` width `li`s).

Answer (score 1):

They are correctly middle-aligned in IE. Try adding a `q` in one of the boxes, and you'll see exactly what I mean.

You can "fix" this and get Chrome's look by adding: `line-height: 18px;`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Chrome and IE have different values for default `line-height`.

Set the `line-height` to `19px` and it should vertically align in both browsers